# Why is the output of this JavaScript function is 10?

Tags: javascript

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yXNQg/) or the below code and tell me why is the output of this script is **10**

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    if (!foo) {
        var foo = 10;
    }
    alert(foo);
}
bar();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `var` in the function, hoists the variable up to the top. As if you declared it at the top of the function, and so `foo` is treated as a local variable in the current scope, the `foo` in the global scope is not affected. Your code is the same as this:

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    var foo;
    if (!foo) {
        foo = 10;
    }
    alert(foo);
}
bar();
```

As you can see, `foo` is declared at the top of the function and is `undefined`, but importantly doesn't get a value until inside the if statement.

Comment: Is there way to check how the code is actually interpreted?

Comment: Can you please explain me what is going on here http://jsfiddle.net/4Wx8j/  as well. I know its something to do with hoisting but I dont really understand why

Comment: You're correct, it's hoisting. Declaring a function like `function ()...` means it will be hoisted up to the top of its parent, just like the `var` in the answer. So the function is declared as `a`, which makes `a` a local, you then assign `1` to `a`, so it's no longer a function, but still treated like a local variable, so the global isn't affected. You can test this theory by changing the inner function to `c`, then you see that the global `a` is modified. I'm not aware of any tool that shows how it's interpretted, but once you understand what is hoisted and what isn't, it's easy to see.

Comment: Thanks MrCode. I like your explanation and your name. MrCode is such a cool name :)